# Не работает форма на AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Всем привет уважаемые. Сразу к проблеме. На локальном сервере отправка писем работает, но на хостинге нет. Думаю, что где то в PHP допустил ошибку. Прошу Вас помочь, если знаете в чем проблема. Заранее благодарен!

У меня есть `HTML` форма

```
<div id="contact-form">        
<div class="controls">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input id="form_email" type="email" class="form-control" required="" data-error="Active email is required.">
        <label for="form_email" class="form-label">Your Email *</label>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input id="form_name" type="text" class="form-control" required="">
        <label for="form_name" class="form-label">Your Name *</label>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div>
        <textarea id="form_message" name="text_comment" class="form-control" rows="4" required="" data-error="Please, leave us a message." placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="messages"></div>
    </div>          
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo SITE_KEY; ?>"></div>

      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <p style="padding-top:8px;">By submitting the data, you will be agreed with our terms of personal data.</p>
        <button type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="button_contacts_home" style="background: none;border:none;outline:none;margin-top:20px;"><span class="btn-white" style="padding-right:48px;padding-left:48px;font-family: 'Inria Sans';font-size:16px;">Send</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И JS код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button_contacts_home").click(function(){
        var name = $("#form_name").val();
        var email = $("#form_email").val();
        var message = $("#form_message").val();
        var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        if (response.length != 0){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "email.php",
                data: {
                    form_name: name,
                    form_email: email,
                    form_message: message,
                    captcha: response
                },
                success: function(data){
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                    document.getElementById('') ("messages").innerHTML = jsonData.result;
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Invalid captcha");
        }
    });
});
```

PHP тоже:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$msg_box = ""; // в этой переменной будем хранить сообщения формы
$errors = array(); // контейнер для ошибок
// проверяем корректность полей
if ($_POST['form_email'] == "")   $errors[] = "E-mail field is empty";
if ($_POST['form_name'] == "")    $errors[] = "Username field is empty";
if ($_POST['form_message'] == "") $errors[] = "Message box is empty";
if ($_POST['captcha'] == "")      $errors[] = "Invalid captcha";

$verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".SECRET_KEY."&response=".$_POST['captcha']);

$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
    $errors[] = "Captcha is not verified";
} else {
    // если форма без ошибок
    if(empty($errors)){     
        // функция отправки письма
        function send_mail($message){
            // почта, на которую придет письмо
            $mail_to = "sales@tapitta.com"; 
            // тема письма
            $subject = "Message from site";
             
            // заголовок письма
            $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
            $headers .= "From: <no-reply@tapitta.com>\r\n"; // от кого письмо
             
            // отправляем письмо 
            mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
        // собираем данные из формы
        $message  = "Username: " . $_POST['form_name'] . "<br/>";
        $message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['form_email'] . "<br/><br/>";
        $message .= "Message: " . $_POST['form_message'];      
        send_mail($message); // отправим письмо
        // выведем сообщение об успехе
        $msg_box = "<span style='color: green;font-size: 16px;'>Thanks for your request! We will get back to you within 48 hours guaranteed!<br/>";

        
        echo "success";
    } else {
        $msg_box = "";
        foreach($errors as $one_error){
            $msg_box .= "<style>.messages{margin-bottom: 20px;}</style><span style='color: red;font-size: 1.2em;'>$one_error</span><br/>";
        }
    }
}
// делаем ответ на клиентскую часть в формате JSON
echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => $msg_box
)); ?>
```

Comment: Все библиотеки подключены (jquery, recaptcha v2)

Comment: Обращайтесь к поддержке хостинга за настройками почты, хотя если это эконом-хостинг, то вряд ли они позволят отправлять почту.

Answer (score 2):

sendmail отключен полагаю на серваке